# Forfiles command : Use slashes instead of backslashes in directory path

Tags: windows, batch-file, backslash

My script is used to remove log files older than `n` days. It is called in a specific context (Spring batch) which has previously initialized several environment variables.

Here's the content of the script :

```
set DAYS = 3
forfiles /p %LOG_PATH% /s /d -%DAYS % /m *.* /c "cmd /c del @FILE"
```

As you can see, I have no control of the value of `LOG_PATH`. It is initialized elsewhere and contains a path with slashes (instead of backslashes) such as this : `D:/DATA/LOGS`

When I launch this script I get, this error : `The directory name is invalid.`

If I manually write the path with backslashes, the command is successful.

So, would it be possible to espace the environment variable so that the command accepts slashes? Or how would you proceed to replace at runtime the slashes by backslashes?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that contrary to what MS docs say, `/m *.*` in `forfiles` does not match all files. It will only match files whose names have an extension. If you want to match *all* files, you need `/m *`. Or just omit `/m` entirely, since `/m *` is the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try with

```
set "DAYS=3"
forfiles /p "%LOG_PATH:/=\%." /s /d -%DAYS% /m *.* /c "cmd /c del @PATH"
```

Where

- `%LOG_PATH:/=\%` will do the slash to backslash replacement.
- Additional quotes are included to handle problems with spaces or special characters.
- There is an additional dot at the end to avoid problems if the variable contains an ending slash, that will be converted to a backslash and will escape the quote.
- Variable `%DAYS%` definition changed to remove spaces in name and value
- `forfiles /s` asks for recursive search, and `@FILE` will only retrieve the name and extension of the file, so it is changed to `@PATH` to ensure the code will only remove found files out of current active directory.

If you don't have control on the contents of `%LOG_PATH%` and don't know if the variable contains quotes, quoting again the variable can lead to more problems. A safer version could be

```dos
set "DAYS=3"
for %%a in ("%LOG_PATH:"=%.") do (
    forfiles /p "%%~fa" /s /d -%DAYS% /m *.* /c "cmd /c del @PATH"
)
```

Where the quotes in the variable (if present) are removed and the path corrected when requesting the full path to the element referenced by the `for` command

Comment: Thanks a lot, the variable may contains quotes, so I'll use your safer version! Although, I'm not quite sure I understand the difference between `@FILE` and `@PATH`. Does my previous script remove files from subdirectory and yours don't?

Comment: @Thrax, [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) says `@FILE` is only the file name and `@PATH` includes the full path to the file. In theory the current active directory is set to the one being iterated by `forfiles` to execute the indicated command inside that directory so there will be no difference, but just to prevent problems (and here we are deleting files) I have the habit to precisely state what the code should do. While probably not needed at all,  indicating the full path is safer. Just an habit.

Comment: Yup, I was reading the documentation to see if I could suppress `ERRORLEVEL` in case of no files found (which I managed to do) and if I could echo the number of files deleted (still working on it). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

[Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

```
==> set "LOG_PATH=D:/DATA/LOGS"

==> echo %LOG_PATH%      %LOG_PATH:/=\%
D:/DATA/LOGS      D:\DATA\LOGS

==>
```

Some mistakes:

```
          v  this space
set DAYS = 3                                                
forfiles /p %LOG_PATH% /s /d -%DAYS % /m *.* /c "cmd /c del @FILE"
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^                       ^^^^^  
              results to  /d - 3                            use fully qualified @PATH
                              ^  this space
```

Hence, use (quotes and trailing dot in `"%LOG_PATH:/=\%."` by virtue of *MC ND*)

```
set "DAYS=3"
forfiles /p "%LOG_PATH:/=\%." /s /d -%DAYS% /m *.* /c "cmd /c del @PATH"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try [variable search/replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) like:

```
set DAYS = 3
forfiles /p %LOG_PATH:/=\% /s /d -%DAYS % /m *.* /c "cmd /c del @FILE"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!